# Hot to implemet notification direct reply in Ionic2

Tags: push-notification, ionic2

Is it possible to implement direct reply using Ionic2? I'm looking for a way to capture a users response directly from the notification (style WhatsApp) without them having to open the app.

I'm using the phonegap-plugin-push plugin to handle notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to see a plugin like that too, i am currently using the Ionic deeplink plugin and open the message dialog directly in the app. https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/ionic-deeplinks/